# Import Only Second Column of CSV into MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I want to import the second column of a CSV file into MySQL.  Here's the CSV file:

```
Name,Source,Follows
John,Youtube,Y
Kat,FB,N
Jacob,Twitter,N
```

Here's the code I have so far:

```
DROP TABLE temp;

CREATE TABLE temp
(ID          INT               AUTO_INCREMENT          primary key,
sn           VARCHAR(50)
);

DESCRIBE temp;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/...temp.csv' INTO TABLE Person
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@col2) set sn=@col2;

SELECT * FROM temp;
```

However, I get that there is an empty set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

File: `/path/to/temp.csv`:

```bsh
Name,Source,Follows
John,Youtube,Y
Kat,FB,N
Jacob,Twitter,N
```

MySQL Command-Line:

```sql
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `temp`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp` (
    ->   `ID` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `sn` VARCHAR(50)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/temp.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE `temp`
    ->   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    ->   IGNORE 1 LINES
    ->   (@`null`, `sn`, @`null`);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT `ID`, `sn`
    -> FROM `temp`;
+----+---------+ 
| ID | sn      |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Youtube |
|  2 | FB      |
|  3 | Twitter |
+----+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE**

```sql
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/temp.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE `temp`
    ->   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    ->   IGNORE 1 LINES
    ->   (@`null`, `sn`);
Query OK, 3 rows affected, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 3

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                   |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1262 | Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns |
| Warning | 1262 | Row 2 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns |
| Warning | 1262 | Row 3 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `ID`, `sn`
    -> FROM `temp`;
+----+---------+
| ID | sn      |
+----+---------+
|  1 | Youtube |
|  2 | FB      |
|  3 | Twitter |
+----+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This did work - thanks!  But is there a way to do this for a much larger csv file?  Let's say it had 100 columns.  Is there a way to get only the second column's information?

Comment: @billyl320: See updated answer. `If an input line has too many fields, the extra fields are ignored and the number of warnings is incremented.`, see [13.2.6 LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

Comment: Ah okay - thanks. Any idea how this might change if I wanted to get the 50th column out of 100?